# Extract last 2 snippets from string (PHP)

Tags: php, string, symfony, replace

In my code I call the following up

```
{$item.articlename}
```

this one has the content:

> "Red Blue Green Yellow Black"

I just want to have the last two words in the string.

> "Yellow Black"

I tried to delete the first words with regex_replace,

```
{$item.articlename|regex_replace:"/^(\w+\s)/":" "}
```

but the number of words at the beginning varies, so I always want to have the last two words.

I would appreciate any hint.

Comment: You could match `\w+\h+\w+$` or use `^.*(\b\w+\h+\w+)$` and replace with group 1 `$1` https://regex101.com/r/GhNr0O/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match the last 2 words using `\w+` to match 1+ word characters and `\h+` to match 1+ horizontal whitespace characters. Use an anchor `$` to assert the end of the string.

Note that `\s` also matches a newline.

```
\w+\h+\w+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xqLXqS/1)

If you want to use a replacement, you could replace using the first capturing group and use a word boundary `\b` before the first `\w+`

```
^.*(\b\w+\h+\w+)$
```

- `^` Start of stirng
- `.*` Match any char except a newline 0+ times
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\b\w+\h+\w+` Wordboundary, 1+ word chars, 1+ horizontal whitespace chars, 1+ word chars
- `)` Close group 1
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ULvga2/1)

In the replacement use group 1 `$1`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming last 2 words would **always** exist, you can use simple [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [array_slice()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) with a negative offset to get them. Later, you can glue them using [join](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.join.php).

```
<?php

$str = "Red Blue Green Yellow Black";

echo join(" ",array_slice(explode(" ",trim($str)),-2));
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/7FJ9n

In your code, it would look like

```
{{ join(" ",array_slice(explode(" ",trim($item.articlename)),-2)) }}
```

Comment: P.S Not a Symfony dev, but looks like you can use the interpolation `{{}}` syntax https://symfony.com/doc/2.0/quick_tour/the_view.html#getting-familiar-with-twig

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$string = "Red Blue Green Yellow Black";
$arr = explode(" ", $string);
$arr = array_slice($arr, -2, 2, true);
$result = implode(" ", $arr);
```